# JQuery: thumbnails scroll automatically based on mouse position

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, autoscroll

I'm trying to make a row of thumbnails scroll automatically within their DIV depending on where the mouse is. I found an example of what I'm after [here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailsNavigationGallery/), but can't extract/edit the JavaScript to make it work properly. [Here](http://gaelen.co.za/example5/) is my failed attempt. :(

I need the parent DIV to fill the full width of the page (i.e.100%). Eventually, if I get this right, I would like to add more than one auto scrolling thumbnail DIV on a page.

Sorry if the code is bad, my knowledge of JavaScript is **abysmal**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close, although you had a mismash of javascript and perl variables, etc.

Some notes:

- `$` is used as an alias for `jQuery`.  So, `$()` is the same as `jQuery()`.  It is not a variable identifier like in perl.
- `$div` should be `$('div')`, but it is not very useful if you are immediately going to call `children()` or `find()`.  Instead do `$('div.album')`
- Instead of calculating the width using `63 * number_of_elements`, use jQuery to get their actual widths using `.outerWidth(true)`.  The `true` means it includes margins.

Here is a working example based off your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/BAjQB/

I added variables `leftBuffer` and `rightBuffer` which constrain the scrolling so that you don't have to be on the very edge pixel to scroll all the way left/right.

Comment: Wow, you're a legend! Thank you very much for the help!